# Failure to connect to Node.js web server from Arduino Ethernet Shield

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, arduino

It is my intention to create a persistent connection between my Arduino (via an Ethernet Shield) to a Node.js web server using express and Socket.IO - this is so I can send data to and from the web server without having to open and reopen the connection.

Unfortunately I am rather new to both the world of Arduino and Node and I seem to be falling at the first hurdle, I have used various pieces of code I have found around the internet to create both the server and client but to no avail.

Please see below for code snippets:

**Arduino Code**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x96 };

char server[] = { 192, 168, 1, 2 };

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server 
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(5000);

  Serial.println(server);

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac);
  }

  delay(5000);

  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
    // print the value of each byte of the IP address:
    Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
    Serial.print("."); 
  }

  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 3000)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.write("GET / HTTP/1.1");
  } 
  else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available 
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while(true);
  }
}
```

**Node code**

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); // this tells socket.io to use our express server

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);


console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('A new user connected!');
    socket.emit('info', { msg: 'The world is round, there is no up or down.' });
});
```

**Execution results - Serial Monitor**
Going on this image it looks as if the shield appears to make a connection with something, however the connection drops immediately (apologies for use of imgur, i don't have enough rep to post images yet!)
[image: Disconnect]

**Execution results - Node console**
As you can see node doesn't share the Arduino monitors enthusiasm regarding a connection being made and sits idle.
[image: Idle Connection]

Any help, tips or advice would be appreciated at this stage, I've been battling with this for the last few days and tried various different types of servers and the same thing happens regardless.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Note closely the terminators required in HTTP, see

[HTTP protocol at W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html)

The server will be exacting in its requirements the client follows the protocol.  Note closely the termination in section 5 and 5.1:

The entire request is:

*Request = Request-LineCRLF*

and one line in your case is:

*Request-Line = GET / HTTP/1.1CRLF*

Combined that means there are 2 pair of CR LF at the end of a simple request.

Try:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
```

You should then see the server acknowledge a request.

Comment: Thanks for your response and apologies for the late reply! The issue here was I was trying to talk to a WebSockets server using HTTP requests! That clearly isn't going to work!